# How does Python convert floats to strings internally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, floating-point, cpython

In [part of Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), there is a part that says:

> Interestingly, there are many different decimal numbers that share the same nearest approximate binary fraction. For example, the numbers `0.1` and `0.10000000000000001` and `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` are all approximated by `3602879701896397 / 2 ** 55`. Since all of these decimal values share the same approximation, any one of them could be displayed while still preserving the invariant `eval(repr(x)) == x`.
> Historically, the Python prompt and built-in `repr()` function would choose the one with 17 significant digits, `0.10000000000000001`. Starting with Python 3.1, Python (on most systems) is now able to choose the shortest of these and simply display `0.1`.

From what I understand, this means that when Python converts a float to a string, it chooses the shortest string that is exactly equal to the internal representation when approximated. I tried to figure out how it does this by looking through the CPython source code, but the farthest I got was this:

```c
static PyObject *
float_repr(PyFloatObject *v)
{
    PyObject *result;
    char *buf;

    buf = PyOS_double_to_string(PyFloat_AS_DOUBLE(v),
                                'r', 0,
                                Py_DTSF_ADD_DOT_0,
                                NULL);
    if (!buf)
        return PyErr_NoMemory();
    result = _PyUnicode_FromASCII(buf, strlen(buf));
    PyMem_Free(buf);
    return result;
}
```

The `PyOS_double_to_string` function is practically a blackbox to me -- it [is documented](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/conversion.html), but I have no idea where it's defined. So...

1. Where is this function defined?
2. What does it actually *do*?

Comment: Here's where the function is defined: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7103356455c8b0c2ba3523929327756413337a31/Python/pystrtod.c#L797-L943

Comment: @JayMody: Wrong function. That's a fallback - there are two versions of the function, and the one you really need to look at is https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7103356455c8b0c2ba3523929327756413337a31/Python/pystrtod.c#L1244

Comment: The bulk of the work is eventually handled by [`Python/dtoa.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aac29af6785712019d34f1a7f15b3c408a4f68ae/Python/dtoa.c), which is 2860 lines long and way too much code to describe in detail.

Comment: Re “when Python converts a float to a string, it”: Note that Python is not one thing. The Python standard is not strict about this or other floating-point behavior, so each implementation may do different things.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes to see the exact values near "0.1" to help advance the understanding of OP's question.

```
A next lower float ..... 0.09999999999999999167_332731531132594682276248931884765625
B average A,C .......... 0.09999999999999999861_2221219218554324470460414886474609375
C nearest float to "0.1" 0.10000000000000000555_11151231257827021181583404541015625
D C to 17 places ....... 0.10000000000000001
E average C,F .......... 0.10000000000000001249_0009027033011079765856266021728515625
F next upper float ..... 0.10000000000000001942_890293094023945741355419158935546875
```

All of the decimal values between B,E approximate to 3602879701896397 / 2 ** 55.  This includes: 0.1.